# Что не так с запросом PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT id_customer, COUNT(*) as count FROM purchases GROUP BY id_customer HAVING count>5
```

Делаю вот такой запрос и получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR:  column "count" does not exist
LINE 1: ... count FROM purchases GROUP BY id_customer HAVING count>5) A...
```

Что я делаю не так? 
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HAVING` ничего не знает про синонимы из `SELECT`,
потому что логически `SELECT`
[выполяется после](https://jvns.ca/blog/2019/10/03/sql-queries-don-t-start-with-select/).
Используйте функцию без синонима:

```sql
SELECT id_customer
     , COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM purchases
 GROUP BY id_customer
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
SELECT id_customer, COUNT(*) as "count"
FROM purchases 
GROUP BY id_customer 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```